# How do I make a colon a word boundary in vim when searching with * key

Tags: vim

When hitting the <kbd>*</kbd>  key or <kbd>Shift + 8</kbd> on a word like `class::method` the whole thing is selected for searching. Is there a way to configure vim to say if my cursor is on the word method and I hit the <kbd>*</kbd>  key to just select up to the colon so it would look like class::`method`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add or remove `:` from the valid keyword characters list. If you remove `:`, Vim should select only `class`::method or class::`method`, depending where the cursor is:

```
set iskeyword-=:
```

To make it automatic, add to `.vimrc` (in case it's c++):

```
au FileType cpp set iskeyword-=:
```

On the other hand, this will make the whole `class::method` get selected:

```
set iskeyword+=:
```

Comment: thanks that worked will accept once it give me the ability to